# Hash value in Processing code?

Tags: java, processing

I saw some code in a Processing sketch with this value: background(#110000). I understood the function but I didn't understand the value. Can you please explain what it means? Because I know that Processing is mainly Java, when I try to use such a value (with a hash #), Eclipse doesn't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a hexadecimal color code, the same as used in CSS, for example. See [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp), for example.

`#rrggbb` where `rr`, `gg` and `bb` are hexadecimal numbers between `00` and `FF`.

Note: This is not Java syntax, it's valid in Processing but not in Java.

Comment: yeah exactly, how is that valid? I mean Processing is Java right?

Comment: Not exactly, it's Java with some extra syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is the hex code of the color as used in HTML for example.

See here: http://html-color-codes.info/

It goes like this #RRGGBB

where RR is for red, GG is for green and BB is for blue.

Comment: I don't know the exact context you use it in. But that's what it is.